# Why is ColdFusion changing my values when I use <cfqueryparam>?

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion

I am using ColdFusion 9.0.1 and SQL Server 2005.

The column in my database is name Points. It is set up as numeric(6,1).

When I write a query in SQL Server Management Studio to drop in values like 1.2 or 5.5, the numbers store correctly.  When I drop in 1.23 it rounds to 1.2. When I drop in 5.55, it rounds to 5.6.  This is exactly what I expect.

```
UPDATE TableName
SET Points = 1.2
```

When I pass my values to the CFC and DO NOT use CFQUERYPARAM, I get the exact results as described above.

When I pass my values to the CFC uses CFQUERYPARAM, I do not get what I expect. When I drop in a number like 1.2 or 5.5, the value gets rounded to 1.0 or 6.0.

```
UPDATE TableName
SET Points = <cfqueryparam type="CF_SQL_DECIMAL" value="#Points#">
```

I have changed the CFSQLTYPE to CF_SQL_NUMERIC and CF_SQL_DECIMAL.  Still, I cannot get the numbers to save correctly.

When I run the query below in my CFC, the number gets stored as 1.0.

```
UPDATE TableName
SET Points = <cfqueryparam type="CF_SQL_DECIMAL" value="1.23">
```

Can you help me figure out why this isn't behaving as I expect it to?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add the `scale` attribute to your cfqueryparam to let it know how many decimal places to send. Add `scale="2"` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks @DanShort, for the simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It's all about SCALE. I need to add the scale attribute to my CFQUERYPARAM when I use CF_SQL_NUMERIC and CF_SQL_DECIMAL.